# How to handle a sparse array of lists

Tags: matrix, sparse-arrays

I have data in the form of a sparse array of lists. For example:

```
{{76, 17} -> {17803}, {24, 14} -> {18625, 311571, 440371, 818848, 
   2010244, 2317818}, {64, 99} -> {19421, 269349, 397997, 440343, 
   503977, 511172, 1600938, 1656131, 1849185, 1849187, 1974513, 
   2045184, 2065062, 2319929}}
```

The indices are pairs of integers in the range `{0,...,S}^2`.

It seems as it is not possible to store this as a sparse array in Mathematica, as I get the error

> SparseArray::valnl: "The value specified by the rule {76,17}->{17803}
>   should not be a List. "

How would I create an object which provides:

- quick access to the list corresponding to an entry - for example something like `a[[i,j]]` (default is the empty list).
- create a (dense) matrix with the largest list element (default 0)
- create a (dense) matrix with the largest list element not bigger than a given constant

**Update**: Example regarding the last point. If the constant would be 500000, than the entry for `{76,17}` should be `17803`, for `{24,14}` `440371`, for `{64,99}` `440343` and for all other it should be 0.

Comment: 1) Take a loot at `Dispatch` it can be really fast. 2)and 3) are not clear to me.

Answer (score 2):

Apologies if I've misunderstood your questions. I've never used `Dispatch` before, as suggested by Kuba in the comments, but it seems to be the right tool for the problem if speed is your concern.

First off, I hope it's clear that accessing the list corresponding to an index pair is as straightforward is applying the rules list for pattern replacement:

```
rules = {{76, 17} -> {17803}, {24, 14} -> {18625, 311571, 
     440371, 818848, 2010244, 2317818}, {64, 99} -> {19421, 269349, 
     397997, 440343, 503977, 511172, 1600938, 1656131, 1849185, 
     1849187, 1974513, 2045184, 2065062, 2319929}}
drules = Dispatch[rules~Append~(_ -> {})]
(* Note that I've added an additional rule at the end for the "default case" *)
{64, 99} /. drules

(* returns {19421, 269349, 397997, 440343, 503977, 511172, 1600938, 1656131, \
1849185, 1849187, 1974513, 2045184, 2065062, 2319929} *)
{100, 100} /. drules
(* returns {} *)
```

You can easily write it as a function.

Regarding creating "a (dense) matrix with the largest list element (default 0)" - if I've understood correctly - you could do:

```
Normal@SparseArray@MapAt[Max, rules, {All, -1}]
```

And for the "create a (dense) matrix with the largest list element not bigger than a given constant" bit:

```
With[{c = 500000}, 
  SparseArray@
   MapAt[Max@Select[#, Function[x, x <= c]] &, 
    rules, {All, -1}]];

% // ArrayRules 
(* gives {{24, 14} -> 440371, {64, 99} -> 440343, {76, 17} -> 17803, {_, _} -> 
  0} *)
```

If your lists are in ascending order (as they are in your example), then you could replace the `Select` with `TakeWhile` and the `Max` with `Last`. I imagine that might be faster.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. `Dispatch` seems a good way. I am not sure if I understand the last bit using `Clip` correctly and updated my question to make clear what I am looking for.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized my mistake in understanding your requirement. I'll fix the code in a bit.

Comment: @Danvil fixed it

Answer (score 1):

You could define a function `f` that does the lookup for you:

```
rules = {{76, 17} -> {17803},
         {24, 14} -> {18625, 311571, 440371, 818848, 2010244, 2317818},
         {64, 99} -> {19421, 269349, 397997, 440343, 503977, 511172, 1600938, 1656131, 1849185, 1849187, 1974513, 2045184, 2065062, 2319929}};

Clear[f];
rules /. (a_ -> b_) :> (f[Sequence @@ a] = b);
f[_, _] = {};
```

Try it out:

```
f[76, 17]
(*    {17803}    *)

f[1, 2]
(*    {}    *)
```

Generate a matrix with largest elements not larger than `m` (set `m=∞` for using largest elements):

```
With[{m = 500000},
  rules /. (a_ -> b_) :> (a -> Max[Select[b, # <= m &]])] /. -∞ -> 0
(*    {{76, 17} -> 17803,
       {24, 14} -> 440371,
       {64, 99} -> 440343}    *)

% // SparseArray
(*    sparse array with dimensions 76x99    *)
```